# PicklingError: Could not pickle the task to send it to the workers

Tags: python, pickle

I am working on an NLP Kaggle project and I am using RandomizedSearchCV in my project. I have defined a function named GO which implements RandomizedSearchCV with KFold and scoring criteria and grid_param. Following is my code and when I call the function **GO**, it gives an error:

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=0, shuffle=True)
acc = lambda y, y_pred: accuracy_score(y, y_pred)
scorer = make_scorer(acc, greater_is_better=True)

def GO(model, grid, n_iter=100):
    search = RandomizedSearchCV(model, grid, n_iter, scorer, n_jobs=-1, cv=kf, random_state=0, verbose=True)
    return search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

This is the error I get:

```
PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-131-310dea03e0ad> in <module>
      3 
      4 for pipe, grid in zip(pipes, grids):
----> 5     fitted_models.append(GO(pipe, grid))

<ipython-input-129-98eb26241ea1> in GO(model, grid, n_iter)
      1 def GO(model, grid, n_iter=100):
      2     search = RandomizedSearchCV(model, grid, n_iter, scorer, n_jobs=-1, cv=kf, random_state=0, verbose=True)
----> 3     return search.fit(X_train, y_train)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    720                 return results_container[0]
    721 
--> 722             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    723 
    724         results = results_container[0]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1513         evaluate_candidates(ParameterSampler(
   1514             self.param_distributions, self.n_iter,
-> 1515             random_state=self.random_state))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params)
    709                                for parameters, (train, test)
    710                                in product(candidate_params,
--> 711                                           cv.split(X, y, groups)))
    712 
    713                 all_candidate_params.extend(candidate_params)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    928 
    929             with self._backend.retrieval_context():
--> 930                 self.retrieve()
    931             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
    932             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    831             try:
    832                 if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
--> 833                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    834                 else:
    835                     self._output.extend(job.get())

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in wrap_future_result(future, timeout)
    519         AsyncResults.get from multiprocessing."""
    520         try:
--> 521             return future.result(timeout=timeout)
    522         except LokyTimeoutError:
    523             raise TimeoutError()

~\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    430                 raise CancelledError()
    431             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 432                 return self.__get_result()
    433             else:
    434                 raise TimeoutError()

~\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in __get_result(self)
    382     def __get_result(self):
    383         if self._exception:
--> 384             raise self._exception
    385         else:
    386             return self._result

PicklingError: Could not pickle the task to send it to the workers.
```

I tried to resolve it but can't do. Can anyone here help me?

Comment: Whats's in `model`?